# EF Add Object is a child object automatically created?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have a Parent object which contains foreign key references to the Child table and I add a Child to the Parent do I need to call Context.Add() on both the child and the parent separately? or just the parent?

given that:

```
Parent.childobj=child;//foreign key reference set to the child object
```

This:

```
mycontext.Add(Child);
mycontext.Add(Parent);
```

or

```
mycontext.Add(Parent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both entities already exist and you want to relate the child with the parent, and also the parent entity is been tracked by the context, updating the FK property is enough.

```
Parent.ChildId=child.Id;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now if `Child` is a new entity and parent already exist and has been tracked by the context, then use the reference property to associate both:

```
Parent.childobj=child; // You can also do this if both exist already in your DB
context.SaveChanges();
```

If both are new then add the parent to the context, that will persist also the related child:

```
Parent.childobj=child;
context.Parent.Add(parent);
context.SaveChanges();
```